# Scraping data from tables dependent on interactive map

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Another scraping question. I'm trying to scrape data from the following website:
https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/kl-klm/routes

However, the data I want to get only shows up after you click on one of the airports, in the form of a table under the map. From this table, I want to extract the number that indicates the frequency of daily flights to each airport. E.g., if you click on Paris Charles de Gaulle and inspect the country Netherlands from the table, it shows *td rowspan="6"* on the row above, which in this case indicates that KLM has 6 flights a day to Paris.

I'm assuming that I would need to use a browser session like Selenium or something similar, so I started with the following code, but I'm not sure where to go from here as I'm not able to locate the airport dots in the source code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.binary_location = 'C:/Users/C55480/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome SxS/Application/chrome.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/C55480/.spyder-py3/going_headless/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)

airlines = ['kl-klm', 'dy-nax', 'lh-dlh']

for a in airlines:
    url = 'https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/' + a + '/routes'
    page = driver.get(url)
```

Is there a way to make Selenium click on each dot and scrape the number of daily flights for every airport, and then from this find the total number of daily flights to each country?

Comment: It looks like you want someone to write quite big piece of code for you. Try to start coding and in case of issue describe that exact issue

Comment: Maybe I was a bit unclear, but the main issue is that I'm not able to find the airport dots on the map in the source code. I'm guessing that I would first have to locate them and then have Selenium click on each to make the table show up.

Comment: Does it mandatory to use Selenium?

Comment: Not at all, that was just my first thought. As I recently started out I'm not aware of that many alternatives though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using Selenium, try to get required data with direct HTTP-requests:

```
import requests
import json

s = requests.session()
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"}
r = s.get("https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/kl-klm/routes", headers=headers)
```

Data for each airport can be found in script node that looks like

```
<script>var arrRoutes=[{"airport1":{"country":"Denmark","iata":"AAL","icao":"EKYT","lat":57.092781,"lon":9.849164,"name":"Aalborg Airport"}...]</script>
```

To get JSON from `arrRoutes` variable:

```
my_json = json.loads(r.text.split("arrRoutes=")[-1].split(", arrDates=")[0])
```

You need to get abbreviation (value for `"iata"` key) for each airport:

```
abbs_list = []
for route in my_json:
    if route["airport1"]["country"] == "Netherlands":
        abbs_list.append(route["airport2"]["iata"])
```

Output of `print(abbs_list)` should be like `['AAL', 'ABZ'...]`

Now we can request data for each airport:

```
url = "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/kl-klm/routes?get-airport-arr-dep={}"
for abbr in abbs_list:
    cookie = r.cookies.get_dict()
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0",
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
               "x-fetch": "true"}
    response = s.get(url.format(abbr), cookies=cookie, headers=headers).json()
    print(abbr, ": ", response["arrivals"]["Netherlands"]["number"]["flights"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried the code (I assume "abbr_list" is supposed to be "abbs_list" in the last loop) but I get the following error message: 'raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value'

I think I understand what the code is trying to do, but when I manually go to the url "https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airlines/kl-klm/routes?get-airport-arr-dep=ams" it doesn't show the table under the map.

Comment: I also tried using print(BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')), but the line with "rowspan" is still not present. It basically just returns the normal HTML that you would have before clicking on the map.

Comment: We had to add some headers to make it work. Now everything seem to  work fine

Comment: Initially I received errors for certain elements in the last loop, but that was easily fixed with a try and except block. Otherwise it works great, thanks!

Just one question. Regarding the last print line, I assume that the keywords refer to the table, but I didn't quite understand what "number" and "flights" refer to and how they give you the number of daily flights. For instance, let's say that I wanna scrape the aircraft types from the table instead, could that be done by simply changing the keywords in the last line?

Comment: Those keywords refers to keys from JSON. All the data that you see in `<table>...</table>` comes from JSON, so I guess yes, all required data can be received just by using correct JSON keys (you can do `print(my_json)` to see the structure of JSON). Scraping aircraft types will be little more difficult. If you know how JSONPath works, you can simplify this task a little by using [JSONPath for Python](http://mikelev.in/2012/08/implementing-jsonpath-in-python-with-examples/). Or you might need to submit new SO ticket in case you can't get required output

Comment: Also note that there should be no errors with the last code version (I suppose you're using previous version)

Comment: This should return you aircraft types, but looks really messy `for airport in response['arrivals']['Netherlands']['airports']: for flight in response['arrivals']['Netherlands']['airports'][airport]["flights"]: for date in response['arrivals']['Netherlands']['airports'][airport]["flights"][flight]["utc"]: print(response['arrivals']['Netherlands']['airports'][airport]["flights"][flight]["utc"][date]["aircraft"]`

Comment: The above code works well for finding the aircraft types. I have one more question about the first answer. If I change the country to for example Germany instead of Netherlands, the code prints 10 flights, which is correct as KLM has flights to 10 different airports in Germany. However, instead of returning 7 flights to Berlin, it instead returns 46, which is the total number of daily flights to Germany for all 10 airports. For KLM this is fine, as they only have one hub and I can just set the country to Netherlands.

Comment: However, this presents a problem if I run the same code for an airline such as Ryanair, where I would have to loop through several countries as it has multiple airport hubs. I then end up with a total number of daily flights that is higher than it should be. Do you have any suggestions for a possible workaround for this? @Andersson

Comment: Almost two weeks passed and I don't really remember all the details of issue... It would be better if you report new ticket regarding this new issue with your current code, actual and desired output. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The map isn't represented through HTML/CSS so I do no think it is possible to interact with it through Selenium natively.

However, I stumbled upon [Sikuli API](https://code.google.com/archive/p/sikuli-api/), which enables image recognition to interact with Google Maps (like on the page you linked), Captchas, ... You could crop that marker and try to use Sikuli to recognize it and click on it. See http://www.assertselenium.com/maven/sikuliwebdriver-2/ for a small example on how to use it.

The data in the tables can however easily be selected using Xpaths and parsed using a tool like Selenium. It seems however that Sikuli is usable only in Java so you'll have to use Selenium with Java too.